# how does one define a nullary function in python?

Tags: python

How does one define a nullary function in Python, that is, a function with no arguments? For example, I might want to define a function that always returns a certain value.

Comment: `def nullary():return "I am nullary"`, Take care of indentation though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a function with two arguments, you list two arguments:

```
def func(one_argument, another):
```

To define a function with zero arguments, you list zero arguments:

```
def func():
#        ^ nothing there
```

Same as any other nonnegative integer number of arguments.